# Type 'Right<SearchCepError, ViaCepInfo>' is not a subtype of type 'String?' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart, either, dartz

I'm trying to get the String 'bairro' from this part of code:

**var infoCepJSON = await viaCepSearchCep.searchInfoByCep(cep: '$_cep')**

But, its return a Type Either<SearchCepError, ViaCepInfo>. How can I get the string bairro in this case?

If I put:   _bairro = infoCepJSON.bairro , its wrong because infoCepJSON is not a String but  a object Type Either<SearchCepError, ViaCepInfo> I think.

```
_consultaCep() async {    
  String _cep;


  String _endereco;
  var viaCepInfo = ViaCepInfo();
  var _bairro = bairroController.text;
  final viaCepSearchCep = ViaCepSearchCep();
  _cep = cepController.text;

  var infoCepJSON = await viaCepSearchCep.searchInfoByCep(cep: '$_cep');
  print(infoCepJSON);


  _bairro = infoCepJSON.bairro;
  bairroController.text = _bairro;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

On `either` datatype, you can fold the result. In your case

```dart
infoCepJSON.fold(
  (failure) {},
  (data) {
    // you can get data from here
    
  },
);
```

More about [`Either`](https://pub.dev/documentation/dartz/latest/dartz/Either-class.html)